# How can i encode my class to json to send http put to firebase

Tags: json, flutter

I am trying to encode my class to send a put http to firebase but my function when i prints the User.toMap shows a list with "Instance of 'Address'".

```
{id: -LVsaRJKo3vo6q9NWZn_, name: User 38197, email: null, address: [Instance of 'Address']}
```

```
class User {
  String id;
  String name;
  String email;
  List<Address> address = new List<Address>();

  User({this.id, this.name, this.email, this.address});

  User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    this.id = map['id'];
    this.name = map['name'];
    this.email = map['email'];

    if (map['address'] == null) {
      this.address = new List<Address>();
    } else {
      this.address= (map['address'] as List).map((i) => Address.fromMap(i)).toList();
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {'id': id, 'name': name, 'email': email, 'address': address};
  }
}
```

===

```
class Address {
  String test;

  Address ({this.test});

  Address.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    this.test = map['test'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'test': test
  }
}
```

===

In class ApiProvider

```
Future<User> updateUser(User userUpdate) async {
    String id = userUpdate.id;

    print(userUpdate.toMap()); // This prints that line

    final http.Response response = await http.put(
      baseUrl + '/user/$id.json',
      body: json.encode(userUpdate.toMap()), // Here happens the error
    );

    final Map<String, dynamic> userData = json.decode(response.body);
    User user = new User.fromMap(userData);   

    return user;
  }
```

===

The final error:

```
I/flutter (17495): {id: -LVsaRJKo3vo6q9NWZn_, name: User 38197, email: null, address: [Instance of 'Address']}
E/flutter (17495): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error:     Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (17495): Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Address'
E/flutter (17495): #0      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:703:7)
E/flutter (17495): #1      _JsonStringifier.writeList (dart:convert/json.dart:753:7)
E/flutter (17495): #2      _JsonStringifier.writeJsonValue (dart:convert/json.dart:735:7)
E/flutter (17495): #3      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:693:9)
E/flutter (17495): #4      _JsonStringifier.writeMap (dart:convert/json.dart:786:7)
E/flutter (17495): #5      _JsonStringifier.writeJsonValue (dart:convert/json.dart:741:21)
E/flutter (17495): #6      _JsonStringifier.writeObject (dart:convert/json.dart:693:9)
```

Comment: As far as I remember if you pass a `Map` JSON is assumed and converted automatically.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Sorry i forgot the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {'id': id, 'name': name, 'email': email, 'address': address};
  }
```

needs to be changed to

```
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {'id': id, 'name': name, 'email': email, 'address': address.map((a) => a.toMap()).toList()};
  }
```

Comment: Hey Günter this is not possible because address is a list and toMap() method is in the Address class.

Comment: Yeah! Thank you so much for your time! It´s working!